# UDP + digital signature vs TCP vs other solutions to guarantee message authenticity

Tags: authentication

TCP guarantees message authenticity rather reliably using packet sequence number.
Other option would be going with UDP and using digital signatures to make the message authentic.
What could be my other options (basically are there any I missed)?
Maybe there is some sort of framework which I could use which would allow me to plug into a game engine without writing all authentication logic(each time using tcp i would need that clients login into my system, with udp i would rely on client public signatures inside my db).

TY

Comment: Yes, LIDGREN is a type of framework I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP does not guarantee message authenticity, it only guarantees that all messages are received and that they are received in the order they were sent.

If you want to be sure the messages originate from the source you expected you can use [Diffie-Hellman key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) to establish a key. You can then use that key to encrypt all further messages using [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) or another encryption algorithm. When you implement these algorithms correctly they are secure. (That is the only known way to crack it is by brute-forcing the key). Anyway implementing these algorithms correctly is very hard so it would be best if you would try to find a library that has already implemented these algorithms.

A popular networking library for games is [LIDGREN](http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/) which includes AES encryption, however I'm not sure if it has also implemented D-H key exchange but it should be easy to add this on top.

Comment: With authenticity I meant that you can't spoof IP address:Port of originating packet, that's enough for me to guarantee players authenticity. I'm not worried that somebody is able to intercept packets and change them (MIM). It's not very realistic that other player - hacker could have physical access to the victim's network.
Thank you for the LIDGREN. Seems it is I was looking for. Other suggestions also welcome.

Comment: Ah I understand, well Lidgren is great anyway and it has some security features in case you require them :).

Comment: Strictly speaking, TCP does not even guarantee delivery of all messages. It breaks a _stream of data_ into packets (secretly)  and guarantees that packets are resent unless acknowledged. It reassembles a "stream of data" from the packets on the other end and assures that data on the stream arrives in the order as indicated by the sequence numbers in the packets. It does **not** guarantee that someone hasn't replaced a packet with a different packet having the same sequence number (or sent fake ACKs and dropped packets). Such stuff must be done on a higher protocol level.